# Shell script: create new bash processes

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm trying to quickly batch download Youtube videos. I've created a file, videos.txt, with one video link per line:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**********
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**********
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**********
...
```

I have a shell script that will download the videos:

```
cat videos.txt | while read line; do 
    echo $line
    youtube-dl $line
done
```

However, I want to speed the process up by branching each `youtube-dl` command into its own process/terminal window.
How can I create a **new terminal window/process** for each of the youtube-dl commands?

Note: I've tried to prepend the `youtube-dl` command with `/bin/bash -c` but the script is quite glitchy... it doesn't download all the videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
youtube-dl $line
```

to

```
youtube-dl $line &
```

the `&` starts the job in the background, allowing the parent script to continue.

However, be careful doing this if you've got a long list of urls to grab. Youtube is going to frown on your sucking their site dry, and having too many download processes on your system can grind things to a halt or outright crash it.

Comment: Ah ha! It works! BTW, this is just a test. I don't want to crash Youtube's servers and/or make their sysadmins mad... I have only six videos in my list. :D

Answer (score -1):

Youtube has a section of their terms of service ([Youtube TOS](http://www.youtube.com/t/terms), see 5-B) specifically prohibiting this.